# Image prediction Django API predicts same result and generates errors

Tags: django, api, dart, image-processing, artificial-intelligence

I tried making an API with DJANGO which I call, the api has a function called predictimage which takes the image input from the website (choose file from device on website) and sends it to the api then processes the image (with mediapipe hands to draw a mesh on the image) and then calls the pretrained model and predicts what's in the image.
The problem is that when I predict the first image from the website it works but when I try to choose another file (image) from device and predict another time, it doesn't draw the hand mesh correctly and doesn't make the right prediction (it predicts the same as the first CORRECT image) making the second prediction false.
[This sign is supposed to be A not B and the mesh is not drawn correctly](https://i.stack.imgur.com/09l3J.png)

++IM MAKING THIS API TO CALL IT FROM DART CODE :) is there a solution for this too ? thanks

This is the code

```
#DJANGO
from keras.models import load_model
import cv2
import numpy as np
from cvzone.HandTrackingModule import HandDetector
import math
import time
from django.core.files.base import ContentFile
from django.core.files.storage import default_storage
from django.shortcuts import render
import base64

#imageWhite=[]
detector= HandDetector(maxHands=1)
offset = 20
imgSize = 500
inshape = True
model = load_model("djangomodeltest.h5")
def predictimage(request):
    image_file =None
    imgWhite=[]
    if request.method == 'POST':
        if 'image_input' in request.FILES:
            print("in")
            image_file = request.FILES['image_input']
            # Use the numpy library to read the image file into a numpy array
            img = np.fromstring(image_file.read(), np.uint8)
            img = cv2.imdecode(img, cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
            print(img[0,0])
            hands, img = detector.findHands(img)
            if hands and inshape:
                print("in")
                hand = hands[0]
                x,y,w,h = hand['bbox']
                imgWhite = np.ones((imgSize,imgSize,3),np.uint8)*255
                imgCrop = img[y-offset:y+h+offset,x-offset:x+w+offset]

                imgCropShape= imgCrop.shape


                # READJUSTING HEIGHT AND WIDTH
                aspectRatio= h/w
                if aspectRatio >1:
                    k = imgSize/h     
                    try:    
                        wCal = math.ceil(k*w)      
                        imgResize = cv2.resize(imgCrop,(wCal,imgSize))
                        imgResizeShape = imgResize.shape
                        wGap = math.ceil((imgSize-wCal)/2)
                        imgWhite[0:,wGap:wCal+wGap] = imgResize
                    except:
                        pass

                else:
                    k = imgSize/w     
                    hCal = math.ceil(k*h)      
                    try:
                        imgResize = cv2.resize(imgCrop,(imgSize,hCal))
                        imgResizeShape = imgResize.shape
                        hGap = math.ceil((imgSize-hCal)/2)
                        imgWhite[hGap:hCal+hGap,:] = imgResize
                    except:

                        pass




                imgWhite=cv2.flip(imgWhite,1)

            if img is None:
                return HttpResponse("image not found")
            if img.shape[0] > 0 and img.shape[1] > 0:
                new_img = cv2.resize(img,(50,50))
                pic = np.reshape(new_img,[1,50,50,3])
            else:
                return HttpResponse("invalid image size")
            
            
            for i in imgWhite:
                print(i,sep='-')
            _, img_encoded = cv2.imencode('.jpg', imgWhite)
            img_bytes = base64.b64encode(img_encoded.tobytes()).decode('utf-8')
            labels = ["A","B"]
            
            print(imgWhite.shape)
            print(pic.shape)
            imgWhite = cv2.resize(imgWhite,(50,50))
            imgWhite = np.reshape(imgWhite,[1,50,50,3])
            print(model.input_shape)
            print(imgWhite.shape)
            predictions = np.array([model.predict(imgWhite)])
            my_value="This image represents the sign :  "+labels[np.where(max(model.predict(imgWhite)))[0][0]] 
            context = {'my_value': my_value, 'img_bytes': img_bytes}
            return render(request, 'main/image.html', context)
        else:
            my_value = "pick an image then predict"
            context = {'my_value': my_value}
            return render(request, 'main/image.html', context)
    else:
        return render(request, 'main/image.html')
```

---

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>Predict Image</title>
</head>
<body>
  <h1>Predict Image</h1>
  <form method="post" enctype="multipart/form-data">
    {% csrf_token %}
    <input type="file" name="image_input" accept="image/*">
    <input type="submit" value="Predict">
  </form>
  <p>{{ my_value }}</p>
  {% if img_bytes %}
    <img src="data:image/jpg;base64,{{ img_bytes|safe }}" alt="Predicted Image">
  {% endif %}
  
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.